# What Postgres type would map to a column in hibernate of type Float?

Tags: hibernate, postgresql, jpa

What postgres column type would map to a Java Float type in a hibernate based column?

I have float(19) in my legacy postgres database but if hibernate schema validation is enabled I get this error message.

```
Wrong column type in realtorprint.templatetype for column height.
Found: float8, expected: float4
```

Any ideas?  My column be float(8) instead of float(19) I can probably get this changed in our legacy database.

Comment: I hope you are aware that using floats is a bad idea (in Java as well as in Postgres). Due to the way they are represented you don't necessarily get back what you put in. Using `BigDecimal` (in Java) or `decimal` (in Postgres) is a much better choice. http://floating-point-gui.de/

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Not a universally bad idea; they're excellent for storing the values of measurements and other quantities where exact representation is less important than efficiency and the ability to store values over a huge range of values. Using them for currency is a terrible idea, though.

Comment: I used a float because this width/height column maps to a PDF width/height unit which is fundamentally a floating point number.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

How hibernate maps Java Types to SQL Types is controlled by a subclass of [Dialect](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.1/javadocs/org/hibernate/dialect/Dialect.html) corresponding to your RDBMS.  Precisely which one you use may depend upon your version of both Hibernate and Postgres.

But I suspect in most cases, Java float maps to float(4) and Java double maps to float(8).

This being open source, you can get the code and check to be certain what's happening in your case.

You can also substitute your own dialect through configuration, though it's rarely appropriate.  (It's appropriate for bugfixes occasionally.)